# GreenDao query with distinct

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao, greendao-generator

I`m new to GreenDao and want to load a list by stuffId.I need to use Distinct query to prevent duplicate!
How can I use distinct in my query? below code does not work!!

```
@Override
public ArrayList<DbMaterial> loadMaterialStuffList() {
    openReadableDb();
    final List<DbMaterial> materials= mDaoSession.getDbMaterialDao().queryBuilder().distinct()
            .orderDesc(DbMaterialDao.Properties.StuffId).list();
    mDaoSession.clear();
    if (materials != null) {
        return new ArrayList<>(materials);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: How you you define duplicates? Check this against the definition of SQL Distinct .

Comment: DISTINCT syntax doesn`t operate at all !

Comment: public QueryBuilder<T> distinct()
Use a SELECT DISTINCT to avoid duplicate entities returned, e.g. when doing joins.how to use this structure?

Comment: Why do you think you are getting duplicates? Please post values including the ID.

Comment: I import my database via SQLite Viewer! even I defined stuffId as a unique value and set it as a condition when implement insertOrReplace but I got duplicated values!

Comment: [How do I execute “select distinct ename from emp” using GreenDao](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575658/how-to-use-distinct-in-greendao) [how to use DISTINCT in GreenDao](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445174/how-do-i-execute-select-distinct-ename-from-emp-using-greendao)

Comment: This link may be useful. [How do I execute “select distinct ename from emp” using GreenDao](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445174/how-do-i-execute-select-distinct-ename-from-emp-using-greendao)