# GreenDao, querying for a list of strings

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, greendao

Within my application I have an `Entity / table` that has a Name field (among several other fields). I want a list of Strings of all the unique names found in that table.

Right now the only thing I can think of is to load all the results into a list of `entity objects`, iterate over them, and store the names in a Set, and then convert this Set into a List.

It seems inefficient though. Does `GreenDao` support a feature like this natively or must all queries return `Entity objects`?

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't support it natively. You'll have to use the rawQuery approach and pass either a DISTINCT or GROUP BY sql query.

Usage of rawQuery for this scenario has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23468447/1202600)

Comment: How exactly? What does the code look like for using the rawquery approach?

Comment: @KaliMa: I added a link to another SO post which contains an example.